# BPEL compilation error: undeclared variable

Tags: java, bpel, apache-ode

I'm using Eclipse BPEL Designer and Apache ODE. Then I'm trying to deploy my process in `catalina.out` I'm getting error `org.apache.ode.bpel.iapi.ContextException: Deploy failed; error: [CompilationErrors] Compilation completed with 1 error(s):
    null:138: error: [UndeclaredVariable] Attempt to reference undeclared variable "expertSelectionResponse1"`.

Here is my BPEL code: 
    `

```
<bpel:process name="pskov"
     targetNamespace="http://localhost.pskov"
     suppressJoinFailure="yes"
     xmlns:tns="http://localhost.pskov"
     xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
     xmlns:ns="http://pskov.ru"

     xmlns:ode="http://www.apache.org/ode/type/extension"
     xmlns:ns0="http://createtask.pskov.ru/" xmlns:ns2="http://selectexpert.pskov.ru/">

<!-- Import the client WSDL -->
<bpel:import namespace="http://selectexpert.pskov.ru/" location="SelectExpert.wsdl"  

importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
<bpel:import namespace="http://createtask.pskov.ru/" location="CreateTaskwsdl.wsdl"  
importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>

<bpel:import namespace="http://pskov.ru" location="InspectionWriter.wsdl"  
importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
<bpel:import location="pskovArtifacts.wsdl" namespace="http://localhost.pskov" 
        importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />

<!-- ================================================================= -->         
<!-- PARTNERLINKS                                                      -->
<!-- List of services participating in this BPEL process               -->
<!-- ================================================================= -->         
<bpel:partnerLinks>
    <!-- The 'client' role represents the requester of this service. -->
    <bpel:partnerLink name="client"
                 partnerLinkType="tns:pskov"
                 myRole="pskovProvider"
                 />


    <bpel:partnerLink name="WriteInspectionPL"  
partnerLinkType="tns:WriteINspectionPLT"  
partnerRole="WriteInspectionRole"></bpel:partnerLink>

    <bpel:partnerLink name="CreateTaskPL" partnerLinkType="tns:CreateTaskPLT"  
partnerRole="CreateTaskRole"></bpel:partnerLink>
    <bpel:partnerLink name="SelectExpertPL" partnerLinkType="tns:SelectExpertPLT"  
partnerRole="SelectExpertRole"></bpel:partnerLink>
</bpel:partnerLinks>

<!-- ================================================================= -->         
<!-- VARIABLES                                                         -->
<!-- List of messages and XML documents used within this BPEL process  -->
<!-- ================================================================= -->         
<bpel:variables>
    <!-- Reference to the message passed as input during initiation -->
    <bpel:variable name="input"
              messageType="tns:pskovRequestMessage"/>

    <!-- 
      Reference to the message that will be returned to the requester
      -->
    <bpel:variable name="output"
              messageType="tns:pskovResponseMessage"/>


    <bpel:variable name="WriteInspectionPLResponse"  
messageType="ns:writeToDBResponse">   
</bpel:variable>
    <bpel:variable name="WriteInspectionPLRequest" messageType="ns:writeToDBRequest"> 
</bpel:variable>


    <bpel:variable name="CreateTaskPLResponse"  
messageType="ns0:writeTaskToDBResponse">   
</bpel:variable>
    <bpel:variable name="CreateTaskPLRequest" messageType="ns0:writeTaskToDB">   
</bpel:variable>
    <bpel:variable name="SelectExpertPLResponse1"  
messageType="ns2:expertSelectionResponse"></bpel:variable>
    <bpel:variable name="SelectExpertPLRequest1" messageType="ns2:expertSelection"> 

</bpel:variable>
</bpel:variables>


<!-- ================================================================= -->         
<!-- ORCHESTRATION LOGIC                                               -->
<!-- Set of activities coordinating the flow of messages across the    -->
<!-- services integrated within this business process                  -->
<!-- ================================================================= -->         
<bpel:sequence name="main">

    <!-- Receive input from requester. 
         Note: This maps to operation defined in pskov.wsdl 
         -->

    <bpel:receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="client"
             portType="tns:pskov"
             operation="process" createInstance="yes" variable="input"/>

    <!-- Generate reply to synchronous request -->
    <bpel:assign validate="no" name="CopyInstanceIDToOutput"><bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from><bpel:literal><tns:pskovResponse 
xmlns:tns="http://localhost.pskov" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance">

    <tns:result>tns:result</tns:result>
  </tns:pskovResponse>
  </bpel:literal></bpel:from>
            <bpel:to variable="output" part="payload"></bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>
        <bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from    
expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">









                <![CDATA[$ode:pid]]>
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to part="payload" variable="output">
                <bpel:query  
queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:result]]>  
</bpel:query>
            </bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>

    </bpel:assign>
    <bpel:reply name="replyOutputWithinstanceID" partnerLink="client"   
portType="tns:pskov" operation="process" variable="output" />
    <bpel:assign validate="no" name="CopyTagToSelectActivity">
        <bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from><bpel:literal><tns:pskovResponse 
xmlns:tns="http://localhost.pskov" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-  
instance">

 <tns:result>ns2:expertSelectionResponse1</tns:result>
</tns:pskovResponse>
</bpel:literal></bpel:from>
             <bpel:to variable="SelectExpertPLResponse1" part="return"></bpel:to>
         </bpel:copy>





        <bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from part="payload" variable="input">
                <bpel:query     
queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:tagID]]>    
</bpel:query>
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to part="arg0" variable="SelectExpertPLRequest1">
                <bpel:query   
queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[ns2:arg0]]>  
</bpel:query>
            </bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>
    </bpel:assign>
    <bpel:invoke name="SelectExpertByTag" partnerLink="SelectExpertPL"  
operation="expertSelection" portType="ns2:SelectExpertInterface"    
inputVariable="SelectExpertPLRequest1" outputVariable="SelectExpertPLResponse1">   
</bpel:invoke>



    <bpel:assign validate="no" name="CopyExpertName">

        <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes">
            <bpel:from 
expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">


<![CDATA[concat($ns2:expertSelectionResponse1.payload,"123","312","12")]]>
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to part="arg0" variable="CreateTaskPLRequest"></bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>
    </bpel:assign>
    <bpel:invoke name="CreateTask" partnerLink="CreateTaskPL" operation="writeTaskToDB"
portType="ns0:CreateTaskInterface" inputVariable="CreateTaskPLRequest"    
outputVariable="CreateTaskPLResponse"></bpel:invoke>
        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="CopyInputToWriteExpertiseResult">








        <bpel:copy>
            <bpel:from><bpel:literal><impl:writeToDB xmlns:impl="http://pskov.ru"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <impl:allParams>impl:allParams</impl:allParams>
</impl:writeToDB>
</bpel:literal></bpel:from>
            <bpel:to variable="WriteInspectionPLRequest" part="parameters"></bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>

        <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes">
            <bpel:from part="payload" variable="input">
                <bpel:query  
queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:input]]>    
</bpel:query>
               </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="parameters" variable="WriteInspectionPLRequest">
                    <bpel:query   
queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[ns:allParams]]> 
</bpel:query>
                </bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>
        <bpel:invoke name="WriteExpertiseResult" partnerLink="WriteInspectionPL"  
operation="writeToDB" portType="ns1:InspectionWriter"  
inputVariable="WriteInspectionPLRequest" outputVariable="WriteInspectionPLResponse">    
</bpel:invoke>




    </bpel:sequence>
</bpel:process>`
```

As I understand, I need to initialise variable to let ODE know it type. I did it.
Do you see the error? 
How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
Error in this assign operation

```
        <bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes">
            <bpel:from  
expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">

                <![CDATA[concat($ns2:expertSelectionResponse1.payload, 
"123","312","12")]]>
            </bpel:from>
            <bpel:to part="arg0" variable="CreateTaskPLRequest"></bpel:to>
        </bpel:copy>
    </bpel:assign>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ns2:expertSelectionResponse1.payload` is not a valid variable name. The correct name is apparently `SelectExpertPLResponse1`, which is declared to be of type `ns2:expertSelectionResponse`. So the following snippet should work then:

```
<bpel:copy ignoreMissingFromData="yes">
    <bpel:from expressionLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0">
        <![CDATA[concat($SelectExpertPLResponse1.payload, "123","312","12")]]>
    </bpel:from>
    <bpel:to part="arg0" variable="CreateTaskPLRequest"></bpel:to>
</bpel:copy>
```